# How to make RadGridFilter Expressions in Alphabetical order

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

My current scenario is same as like here

[Filter - RadGrid filtering with RadFilter](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/filter/examples/integration/defaultcs.aspx?product=filter)

If we go through this link, here columns are not alphabetical(ORDERID first and last FREIGHT)

grid should be the same way as UN-Ordered/written, but when adding expression/group, filters should be alphabetical order(freight should come first)

trying to load filters alphabetical order while loading grid at page load

Any Help Appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the code below:

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="playersGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <telerik:RadGridView.SortDescriptors> <!-- define initial sorting by name-->
    <telerik:SortDescriptor Member="Name"/>  
    </telerik:RadGridView.SortDescriptors><telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Number}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Country}"/>
  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik admin was suggested below solution.
Can you please try with this:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/sort-the-field-list

Comment: I used that, it doesn't worked for me. Iam trying to get filters in alphabetical order and grid should be same way unordered/prioritized in that way